# Software to simplify displaying build status on a big visible monitor for team?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I had a little bit of budget left at year end and I wanted to start a little skunk works project to display build status what everyone was working on (our team is aobut 10 folks all told). I am thinking to buy a 47" LCD HD TV and drive it from a small pc via a browser/.NET web application.

I was going to build the software over the christmas break since we are closed for 2 weeks starting this Friday. I thought I would solicit advise/feedback on what other teams had done.  a lot of the tools we use SVN, Mantis have RSS feeds that I was thinking to render. Is this the way to go ?

Thanks for any feedback in advance.

Comment: i got the hardware. will start the code shortly. will post the pix later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine is teaching himself how to work with Arduino so that he can build a computer-controlled LED sculpture for Burning Man next year.  His first project?  Using Arduino to control a little array of red and green LEDs so that everyone on his team can look up at it and see if the build is broken and who broke it.

But really, unless that's a road you're interested in going down, in your case I'd write a simple WinForms app that used a FileSystemWatcher to check for changes in the RSS file, an XSLT transform to turn it into HTML, and a WebBrowser to display it.  If you know XSLT and understand the contents of your RSS feed, that's about 2-3 hours of work tops.

Answer (score 2):

Would it really benefit your team in any way?
I'd rather brought something like a table hockey machine to make lunch time more fun.

Comment: We already have air hockey, ping pong and a full size MAME machine. this was more to give visibility to the rest of the company etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the existing solutions first. There is a good summary at http://www.build-doctor.com/2009/08/18/big-visible-continuous-integration/ and http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2009/08/28/big-visible-teamcity.aspx looks interesting.

It all depends on what Continuous integration server you have.

Comment: Cruise control .net. Thanks for the feedback. Gotta take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say stick with RSS. Tried and true and real easy to work with especially in a .NET environment.

Comment: thanks. I am now realizing that I probably need to just integrate a seet of RSS feeds from SVN, our issue tracker. I will have to figure out how to make some graphs from all this to make it "cool".

Comment: sigh. this is why i should never write comments from my iphone.